# Difference between Thread.Abort() and Thread.Suspend()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've never found a solution anywhere.

What is the difference between Suspending threads and aborting threads?

I'm calling a function that keeps hanging till an event is called. I want to stop this thread and the hanging function. Should I suspend or abort the thread?

Comment: Why are you using threads at all?  All the new threading in 4.5 is far superior to `new thread()`.

Comment: Call that function which is hanging in a new thread, do not suspend or abort.

Comment: At this point you shouldn't even use [Suspend according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx): `Thread.Suspend has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202`

Comment: The only way to kill a thread that hangs is to use a watch dog timer so when no activity occurs you can terminate the thread.

Comment: There will be a constant activity that won't stop @jdweng

Comment: Then if it running it is not hanging.  It is doing real processing so there is no way of knowing it is hung.  Then you need a timer that stops the process if it exceeds and specified time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a solid difference between them if you read the msdn documents.

**Abort:** Abort the mission! This method kills the thread (although some survivers may exist)

**Suspend:** Puts the mission on hold. Makes it wait till the `Resume` is called. The thread is unconscious along the way. (this method is deprecated)

Check [Abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Suspend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx) for further understanding, explanations are pretty straightforward.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer if it has enlightened you enough - at least for now.

Comment: Sorry, I had an emergency